# openlayer3 zoom using javascript console?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm taking screenshots of certain website using phantomJS. Currently I take screenshot of selected part of website, now I'd like to customize what map is showing. I can zoom and drag the map in web browser using my mouse. But would this be possible to do "programmaticly" ? Using javascript. I tried some googling and have no clue sadly.

Comment: You can try to [trigger the scroll wheel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404406/trigger-dummy-mouse-wheel-event) or click the zoom buttons if there are any.

Comment: seems like this doesn't work. I dont know why yet. Will dig deeper when i get home and will report back if I manage to get it to work.
thanks for help :)
regards