# Trigger function with onclick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

```
window.addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, _.throttle(parallaxScroll, 60), false);
```

I have an event listener that listens to a mousewheelEvent to trigger a function, yet trying to trigger that function directly (on a different page, using react) will invariably only pass a mouseclick event. What's something I can listen to via DOM to trigger the function as a mousewheelEvent when someone onclicks a button?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events, https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#wheel-events What is a "mousewheelEvent"? It seems to be fairly deprecated. Have you tried simply `window.addEventListener("wheel", ......`?

Comment: Yes, it is the old school version of wheel. I'm wondering if there's a way to perhaps to use an onclick to trigger a natural scroll to trigger the listener to the scroll or pass off a scroll through an onclick.

Answer (score 0):

[Trigger 'dummy' mouse wheel event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404406/trigger-dummy-mouse-wheel-event)

The short of it, is that you cannot trigger a dummy mouse event. The second best option is to create a new function that closely matches what the scroll or wheel event triggers and utilize that on the onClick.